# Heroku Dyno inexplicably down?

Tags: node.js, heroku, wakeup, dyno

I've used Heroku to host my Discord bot for a while now with no problems. I connected it with Github to autodeploy after every commit. However, today I made a change in one of the bot's files, a normal change that I've done before, and now after committing, the bot is offline on Discord. I have the free Heroku plan, and I've checked and I still have 100 dyno hours left this month. I'm kind of new to all of this and I'm not very experienced.
Also, the dyno app's wakeup link does not wake the dyno up or bring it back online.
Any input is appreciated. Thanks.
And for the record: The bot is not down because it's not timed out on the free plan, I made sure of that. Also it's set to worker, not web, so that shouldn't be the issue. And lastly, I have not run out of hours.

Logs:

```
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083329+00:00 app[web.1]: db error Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083337+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083338+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083338+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083339+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083340+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1223:12)
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083341+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083344+00:00 app[web.1]:   fatal: true,
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083344+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
2020-10-22T16:58:50.083345+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-22T16:59:28.144872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=alt-bot-test.herokuapp.com request_id=cc359a55-b215-460b-88b2-f30011cc2f4b fwd="189.159.10.29" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=150 protocol=https
2020-10-22T16:59:28.477327+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alt-bot-test.herokuapp.com request_id=80f4874a-f2ca-4c47-a557-be7b5e91426e fwd="189.159.10.29" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=150 protocol=https
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638151+00:00 app[web.1]: db error Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638161+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638162+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638162+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638165+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638166+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1223:12)
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638166+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638168+00:00 app[web.1]:   fatal: true,
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638168+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
2020-10-22T16:59:49.638169+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you changed a file with database connection information? Could you possibly revert the change you made and repush old code, to see if your app works again?

Comment: That was precisely the problem. Thanks.